# How do I set up Google PageSpeed Service for my site?

Tags: google, page-speed, google-app-engine

It seems I can't set up Google's PageSpeed Service. When I do it in the Google services panel, a message comes up like: "Your site may be directing live traffic."

What can I do to resolve this and activate the PageSpeed service? It is for a Google App Engine app that has its own domain.

**Update:**

[image]

I don't know what the above means. I must have succeeding in verifying the domain as I'm using it from google apps and google appengine.

Comment: I would suggest joining this Google group for PageSpeed and asking if anyone's had issues using it with Google App Engine:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/page-speed-service-discuss

It could still be an issue regarding your DNS setup, but check there first regarding Google Apps to make sure there isn't a limitation, because Google would be your host for both services in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google's PageSpeed Service](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service) is for any website domain, so it should work for custom domains using Google App Engine.

You will however first have to modify your domain's DNS with a `DNS TXT` record containing a verification string to let Google know that you do in fact own the domain. Then you'll have to create a CNAME record that points to `pagespeed.googlehosted.com`

You might be receiving the message you're seeing because you missed one of these steps, or the service cannot connect to the supplied host.

For more information, see the following section [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/use-google-pagespeed-service-to-optimize-your-web-page-performance/1854):  "How can I start using PageSpeed?" This also contains helpful information on what Google's PageSpeed Service does and how to use it.

This provides a comprehensive review of it as well: [Google PageSpeed Service Review](http://www.x-pose.org/2012/12/google-pagespeed-service-review/)

Answer (score -1):

The PageSpeed Insights will work for any URL.

Head over here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights and enter the URL you want to find out PageSpeed Insights on.

Comment: The question is about "PageSpeed Service" not "PageSpeed Insights".  The service runs on your webserver.  They are not asking about the speed measuring browser plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Press F12 when in Google Chrome as it is part of the inspect element devtools now. You'll see PageSpeed as an option in the top menu which you can launch when on any page in the browser.

Comment: The question is about "PageSpeed Service" not "PageSpeed Insights".  The service runs on your webserver.  They are not asking about the speed measuring browser plugin.