# How do I setup origin domain for Google PageSpeed Service?

Tags: wordpress, dns, vps, page-speed

I have a WordPress site with cPanel (WHM) with VPS. Today I configured Google PageSpeed Service for my WordPress site. After I submitted my `WWW` domain, PSS automatically added my naked domain (without `www`) to Hosted By You. PSS works few hours without any issue. Now it's giving me "Fetching content failed due to a DNS error".

According to [this official DNS failure tutorial](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/faq#dnsfailure) I added an origin domain to my WP site. If added `orgin.mydomain.com` (A record) and pointed it to my site IP (VPS main IP), it doesn't display my site. If I added `orgin.mydomain.com` to PageSpeed Service displays a blank site.

How do I fix this issue? How do I setup origin domain name for my site?

Comment: This looks to me like your website will have to be hosted on origin.yoursite.com and then google will server the www. content on your website. By doing this however, you are potentially downing your website for aslong as it takes for your DNS records to propagate

Comment: See my answer and the links in it here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49638/how-do-i-set-up-google-pagespeed-service-for-my-site/49650#49650. If you follow the steps there correctly, it will take time to propagate, but if there are DNS issues after 24 hours (and you've [cleared your DNS cache](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/ClearingBrowserCache)), you can do a lookup [here](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=lookup) to see where your subdomain is pointed to, and a DNS health check [here](http://intodns.com/) to see if there's any other DNS issues.

Answer (score 1):

The `origin` subdomain must point where the `www` subdomain *used* to point.   So if you `www` used to be an A record to the IP address of your host, you need to move that over to `origin`.

That will probably also mean that your server configuration will need to be updated.   The `VirtualHost` directive on it will need to be changed from hosting `www.example.com` to hosting `origin.example.com`.

After your site  is up and running on `origin`, then you can change the `www` subdomain to point to Google's pagespeed service server.